# Group similar strings with numbers and keep order of first appearance

Tags: r, string, sorting, group

I have a dataframe which looks like this example (just much larger):

```
var <- c('Peter','Ben','Mary','Peter.1','Ben.1','Mary.1','Peter.2','Ben.2','Mary.2')
v1 <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7)
v2 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2)
df <- data.frame(var, v1, v2)

      var  v1  v2
1   Peter 0.4 0.5
2     Ben 0.6 0.4
3    Mary 0.7 0.2
4 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
5   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
6  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
7 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
8   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
9  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
```

I want to group the strings in 'var' according to the names without the suffixes, and keep the original order of first appearance. Desired output:

```
      var  v1  v2
1 Peter   0.4 0.5 # Peter appears first in the original data
2 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
3 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
4     Ben 0.6 0.4 # Ben appears second in the original data
5   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
6   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
7    Mary 0.7 0.2 # Mary appears third in the original data
8  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
9  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
```

How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `dplyr::arrange(df, var)` or `df[order(df$var), ]`?

Comment: If the order of unique elements is important `df %>% mutate(var1 = str_remove(var, "\\.\\d+$")) %>% arrange(factor(var1, levels = unique(var1))) %>% select(-var1)`

Comment: This solves the problem for the example I provided, but in my original datastet the numbers behind the '.' range from 1 to 150, so that the result looks like this: 'Peter, Peter1, Peter10, Peter100, ...', however I want to have an consecutive order of the numbers. I will edit my question so it is clearer. @Maël

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create a temporary column without the `.` and the digits (`\\d+`) at the end with `str_remove`, then use `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values or use `match` to `arrange` the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(var1 = str_remove(var, "\\.\\d+$")) %>% 
   arrange(factor(var1, levels = unique(var1))) %>%
   select(-var1)
```

---

Or use `fct_inorder` from `forcats` which will convert to `factor` with `levels` in the order of first appearance

```
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   arrange(fct_inorder(str_remove(var, "\\.\\d+$")))
```

-output

```
     var  v1  v2
1   Peter 0.4 0.5
2 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
3 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
4     Ben 0.6 0.4
5   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
6   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
7    Mary 0.7 0.2
8  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
9  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Compact option with `sub` and `data.table::chgroup`

```
df[chgroup(sub("\\..", "", df$var)),]

      var  v1  v2
1   Peter 0.4 0.5
4 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
7 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
2     Ben 0.6 0.4
5   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
8   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
3    Mary 0.7 0.2
6  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
9  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
```

---

> `chgroup` groups together duplicated values but retains the group order (according the first appearance order of each group), efficiently

Answer (score 1):

`separate` the `var` column into two columns, replace the NAs that get generated with 0, sort and remove the extra columns.

This works on the numeric value of the numbers rather than the character representation so that for example, 10 won't come before 2.  Also, the `match` in `arrange` ensures that the order is based on the first occurrence order.

```
df %>%
  separate(var, c("alpha", "no"), convert=TRUE, remove=FALSE, fill="right") %>% 
  mutate(no = replace_na(no, 0)) %>%
  arrange(match(alpha, alpha), no) %>%
  select(-alpha, -no)
```

giving

```
      var  v1  v2
1   Peter 0.4 0.5
2 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
3 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
4     Ben 0.6 0.4
5   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
6   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
7    Mary 0.7 0.2
8  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
9  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
```

### Update

Have removed what was previously the first solution after reading the update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that the values in `var` are ordered alphabetically, then the simplest solution is this:

```
df %>%
  arrange(var)
      var  v1  v2
1     Ben 0.6 0.4
2   Ben.1 0.9 0.4
3   Ben.2 0.6 0.4
4    Mary 0.7 0.2
5  Mary.1 0.2 0.2
6  Mary.2 0.7 0.2
7   Peter 0.4 0.5
8 Peter.1 0.3 0.5
9 Peter.2 0.4 0.1
```